# Simplecov coverage report seems to miss certain lines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, code-coverage

Just after some clarification on how simplecov determines if a line has been exercised by a test.

I have the following method:

```
def over?
  end_at < Time.zone.now
end
```

in which end_at is an ActiveRecord attribute on the object.

Which is exercised in the following spec:

```
describe CalendarEntry do
  it 'can determine that an event has ended' do
    @entry.end_at = 1.day.ago
    @entry.over?.should be_true
  end
end
```

After running the spec with coverage, it shows the following result:

[image: coverage report]

I've run the test in debug mode with a break point on this line and confirmed that the spec is indeed hitting it.

This isn't isolated to just this line in this method, every line that includes the use of an ActiveRecord associated getter is shown as not covered. Could be coincidence, but seems a bit odd.

Environment: ruby 1.9.3-p327 (mri), rails 3.2.8, simplecov 0.7.1, rspec 2.10.0.

Any ideas on why simplecov thinks it's not covered?

Comment: Do you have a test that will return false for `over?`?  That could explain the method being hit, but not all the results for that code being tested.

Comment: Thanks @PaulFioravanti, I do have a negative test as well and it was run as part of this coverage session.

Comment: Were you able to figure out what the problem was here?  If so, please share!  If not, would you be able to edit your question to include the full text of your spec ie where `@entry` is defined and what the `subject` of the test is.

Comment: I'm having the same kind of problem. I'm using JRuby 1.7.1 in 1.9 mode, Rails 3.2.11 and the latest Simplecov version. Since I have the debug flag warning at every run I think it might be related. If you find a solution keep us informed please.

Answer (score 1):

OK so I add the same kind of problem with JRuby running on Windows.
The answer was actually prompted to me, Simplecov can miss some lines if not runned in debug mode.

```
(j)ruby --debug -S rspec spec
```

With the --debug option it did worked and I was back to 100% coverage as expected.

Comment: It did sound promising, but running (in my case) `ruby --debug bin/rails test:system` did not change the coverage result. My line stays officially not covered, although it clearly is.